# как добавить свой класс в стандартный пакет jdk?

Tags: java

Есть ObjectInputStream, мне требуется добавить в него логированию и складывать в стек все объекты,что записываются.
Решение - расширить существующий класс, но, делать это нужно в том же пакете java.io, но он доступен только для чтения.

Comment: Интересно, для чего нужно объявить класс именно в стандартном пакете. Может, раскроете, какую проблему Вы пытаетесь решить?

Comment: Зачем добавлять новый класс в `java.io`?

Comment: Да, происходит сериализация и падение. Сериализую очень большой объект состоящий из листов. Надо понять, какой из листов выбрасывает stackoverflowerror чтобы разрулить для него циклические ссылки

Comment: поэтому идея добавить в стандартный поток вывода сохранение стека вызовов или хотя бы логирование.

Comment: Думаю, что стоит добавить в вопрос код (де-)сериализации и описание ошибки. Возможно есть более простые решения.

Comment: Это вряд ли циклические ссылки, встроенная сериализация умеет с ними работать (а вот `toString()` для коллекций переполнит стек), просто глубина вложенности большая. То, что вы хотите, делает опция `-Xbootclasspath` ([пример](https://github.com/adrianmalik/oracle-java8-overriding-jdk)), но может быть проще будет настроить в IDE breakpoint при выбросе `StackOverflowError` и поискать там в содержимом коллекций что-то знакомое. Еще можно сделать у вашего объекта свои `readObject`/`writeObject` с логами и прочим (см. док на `Serializable`)

Answer (score 1):

@VladislavOsipenkov это очень плохая идея. Не надо пытаться из-за своей частной проблемы пытаться внедрить свой код в Java SE.

Почему нельзя наследовать от `ObjectInputStream` и сделать свой класс, в котором будет ваше логгирование?

В чем проблема то?